# javascript made '', after split regex

Tags: regex, split

Hello i'm trying regex string.

Just i want remove number. I have this string

'dfmaks1,4412klaikd33,442'

```
var re = new RegExp("[0-9\,]");
var test = 'dfmaks1,4412klaikd33,442';
console.log(test.split(re));
```

Up in code result is

[ 'dfmaks', '', '', '', '', '', 'klaikd', '', '', '', '', '', '' ]

Why make '',s?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXCyI.png)

Comment: If you want to remove, why split? Use `String#replace()`. What is the expected result?

Comment: Try `test.match(/[^0-9,]+/g)` if you need to get two element array with the "words" that do not contain digits/commas.

Comment: Because i want use the strings..... at array So i use split if how to me?

Comment: Wht the hello is it!!! i use match so this problem is done.... really thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may "invert" your regex to match any char *other* than digit/comma (i.e. this [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) - `[^0-9,]`), 1 or more repetitions (add `+` after the character class), using

```js
var test = 'dfmaks1,4412klaikd33,442';
console.log(test.match(/[^0-9,]+/g));
```

The `String#match`, when used with a regex with a global modifier (`/g`), will yield an array of all found non-overlapping match values.

Comment: Really Thank you bro.